# Show a message when user skips a review audit

Tags: feature-request, review-audits

I know that the idea of the review audits is to stop the robo-reviewing. After some review-suspensions I learnt to be more careful and to skip reviews if I'm not sure if they are *good* or *bad*. But I think it would be nice to show a message when user skips a review audit and tell him/her what would be the right way to handle posts like this. Something like:

- You should vote to close questions like this.
- You should approve edits like this.
- You should flag or downvote posts like this.

Comment: Usually I skip things where the area is one that I am not familar with. If I'm going to skip I don't look too deeply. Telling me what I should do with a question I didn't really look at only slows me down

Comment: I'm with Richard here. I might glance at a question, think I don't know anywhere near enough about the subject and don't know whether the change makes a difference to the viability of the question (maybe I don't know why it was closed in the first place) and skip. I don't think I should be encouraged to do things to posts that I'm unsure about.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards this could be solved with the right wording

Comment: Can you suggest any @Jan? I can't think of _any_ reason to warn me that I might want to do something in the future to something that I recognised that I knew nothing about and took the right decision and skiiped.

Comment: I like the idea of a message, similar to the congratulations.  Something like "Congratulations, the previous post was an audit question.  We encourage users to skip posts they are not familiar with".  It might be a good psychological message to send to users that skipping is good.  I don't think it is necessary to tell them how they should have handled it though.

Answer (score 5):

To expand on the discussion in the comments:

Usually I skip things where the area is one that I am not familiar with. Which is of course what I should do. As such all an audit could say is:

> Congratulations, you identified that you didn't know enough about the subject to review it, so didn’t. This is exactly what you should do.

This couldn't actually count as a passed review because then it would be really easy to game by robo-reviewing 10, then skipping until you got an audit then robo-reviewing 10 etc

The alternative is for it to say that the edit/closure was valid/invalid and you should reject/approve/leave closed/reopen it. This has one of 2 outcomes.

- I didn't really read the question, I quickly identified that I wouldn't be able to act on it so skipped. As such this is meaningless noise to me and just slows me down
- As ben is uǝq backwards says, encourages me to act even when I’m unsure, which is 100% the wrong thing to do.

Neither of those outcomes are good